# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error even after following 2 approaches

Tags: cors, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

I am trying to build an angular app to access data from MarkLogic database. I am using MarkLogic rest API to access the data. When I try to run the app, I get the following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.192.75:9550/v1/keyvalue?element=fieldId&value=1005&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have read lot of answers related to this issue on stackoverflow but couldn't get anything working. Here is what I've tried till now.

```
1) Setting the response header using xdmp in qconsole
xdmp:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xdmp:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
xdmp:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type");
2) Tried to add headers by using REST [Extention][1]. Here is the example.sjs file which I wrote.
a) function get(context, params) {
  var results = [];
  context.outputTypes = [];
  for (var pname in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(pname)) {
      results.push({name: pname, value: params[pname]});
      context.outputTypes.push('application/json');
    }
  }
  context.outputStatus = [201, 'Created My New Resource'];
    context.outputHeaders = 
    {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'GET, OPTIONS, DELETE', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'x-requested-with, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type'};
  return xdmp.arrayValues(results);
};
exports.GET = get;
b) curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X PUT -i -H "Content-type: application/vnd.marklogic-javascript" --data-binary @./example.sjs http://192.168.192.75:9550/LATEST/config/resources/example
```

It doesn't seem to work, either ways. Can anyone please tell me if I am doing anything wrong? or If there are any other ways to get this working? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative way I found is to define my own transform. This helps only for GET request method not for others. Here is what I created.

```
function customCors(context, params, content)
{
    xdmp.addResponseHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    xdmp.addResponseHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods' , 'GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE' );
    xdmp.addResponseHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , 'X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Accept');
    return content;
};

exports.transform = customCors;
```

to use this we have to use a property called transform. Like this.

> http://192.168.192.75:9550/v1/keyvalue?element=fieldId&value=1005&**transform=customCors**&format=json

Update: Reached out to MarkLogic, they said this can't be done in a 2-tier approach. We have to have a middle layer(3-tier) like java to add Origins/Methods etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` not allowed to be * when you are doing authentication.  Or it could be due to pre-flight requests which are sent when the request is non-standard.  Pre-flight are OPTIONS requests that are sent prior to the GET/POST/etc. to validate whether the actual call can be made.  The way we have approached this is to front MarkLogic REST endpoints with Apache HTTP as a proxy.  We have the following in a virtualhost configuration.

The ProxyPass is where the proxy to the ML REST endpoint is mapped.  The other stuff sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the name of the requesting host. This is required as '*' is not allowed when authenticating.  The `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` settings are used to respond to the pre-flight OPTIONS request, and just return a HTTP 200 status.

```
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(localhost|domain.com)(:[0-9]+)?$" origin_is=$0
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Authorization, X-User-Id"
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

  # People DB REST Endpoint
  ProxyPass /people_dev http://10.239.12.223:8050
```

You can do the same with NginX or any other HTTP proxy.

Comment: @Tang thanks for your answer. I was looking at a 2 tier approach. i.e. Angular with Marklogic using Rest API. I found an alternate way as of now to achieve this. I'll post it now.